# xmlhttprequest responsetext coming for Accept header: text/xml , but server error for application/JSON

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, content-type, httprequest

I have to get response text from a resourceindex page as  JSON object. When I dont put a Accept header in the request, it shows me the xml response (i see it in an alert)..

But I want the response as a JSON object.. What should I do. One solution would have been

```
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/JSON');
```

but this gives me a server error :500

Also it says

> A message body writer for Java type, class ...., and MIME media type, application/octet-stream, was not found

Can someone suggest on what to do to overcome this and get the response as JSON?

Comment: The correct mime type for JSON is `application/json`, not `application/JSON`. What happens if you try that?

Comment: Hey T.J. Crowder,thanks! that was the problem!! the accept header had to be made in small letters instead of Caps!
So the answer: httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
its json and not JSON

Comment: LOL! And here I'd written it as an answer, then thought "Nah, that's not going to be it, just make it a comment" and deleted my answer. That'll teach me. I've undeleted my answer.

Comment: You might also try 'text/json' instead of 'application/json'

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The correct mime type for JSON is `application/json`, not `application/JSON`. That might be the problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
```

The MIME type is `json` and not `JSON`.

Answer (score -1):

You may also want to add an additional mime of text/javascript as:

```
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json, text/javascript');
```